# Multer middleware does not goes trough and leave request in pending state

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I have a problem with multer middleware.
I created the middleware and set the static express files to the images folder

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

The multer middleware

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES = {
  'image/jpg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/png': 'png'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
  }
});

module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('image');
```

After this, I attached the middleware to the router:

```
router.post('/add-avatar',      multer, addAvatar);
```

The next step is the problem. The middleware does not executing the function at all.
I am trying everything...

```
exports.add = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        let url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
        let imageLink = req.file ? url + '/images/' + req.file.filename : '';

        res.send(imageLink);    
    } 
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I tried to delete the multer middleware and the requests goes thought. I also tried to upload file with postman. But the request is left in pending..
[image]

I dont know what im doing wrong...

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve your issue? I spent countless hours to know why this happens

Comment: yes. dont exactly remember how it worked. but the answer was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below instead:

```js
const multer = require("multer");

const upload = multer({
  dest: "images/",
  limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 },
});

router.post("/add-avatar", upload.single("image"), async (req, res) => {
  let url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host');
  let imageLink = req.file ? url + '/images/' + req.file.filename : '';

  res.send(imageLink); 
});

module.exports = router;
```